# preg_match name and title with information in database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i'm trying to make a script that will get the information about a DJ.
What I want to do is match the DJ title with the DJ name in the table.
if the dj name exists then i want to select that row and use that information.

What i do first is make a list of dj's in a array then i want to match this with the title and if there is a match i want to get the information.

The script i have now is:

```
$ps = $this->db->prepare("SELECT djname FROM `djcrew`");
$ps->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$ps->execute();
$selectit = $ps->fetchALL();
$result01 = preg_match('/'.$selectit.'/', $servertitle, $matches);
$ps01 = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `djcrew` WHERE `djname` = :djname');
$ps01->bindParam(':djname', $matches[0], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$ps01->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$ps01->execute();
$data01 = $ps01->fetchAll();
```

The problem is that i have now is that i get the error array to string conversion
The output of selectit is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [djname] => test04
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [djname] => test03
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [djname] => test02
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [djname] => Test01
        )

)
```

I have tried many things but i cant get this working.

[ Edit ] Add mysql table.

dump of mysql table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `djcrew` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `djname` varchar(48) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `name` varchar(48) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `hobbies` varchar(48) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `other` text NOT NULL,
  `facebook` varchar(48) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `twitter` varchar(48) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `request` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `picname` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `active` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `djcrew` (`id`, `djname`, `name`, `hobbies`, `other`, `facebook`, `twitter`, `request`, `picname`, `active`) VALUES
(1, 'Test01', 'Test - DJ', '', '', '', '', '1', 'test01', '0'),
(2, 'Test02', 'Testing - DJ', '', '', '', '', '1', 'test02', '1'),
```

what i want to get is djname = .. name = .. picname = ..

```
$arr = array('djname' => $data01['djname'], 'name' => $data01['username'], 'picname' => $data01['picname']);
```

Comment: Do you know what array is and what method `PDOStatement::fetchAll()` does in the first place?

Comment: Give us the structure of the table, an example of data and the expected result ...

Comment: added database information and what i want to do with it

Comment: Try printing $selectit , it will be an array.

Comment: i have do this already and added to the question

Answer (score 1):

I think i've found your answer to your original question if this is still the same one

```
$ps = $this->db->prepare("SELECT djname FROM `djcrew`");
$ps->execute();
$selectit = $ps->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$djs= array();

foreach($selectit as $row) {
    $djs[] = $row['djname'];
}

if(in_array($servertitle, $djs) {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM djcrew WHERE djname IN ("' . implode('", "', $djs) . '")';

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

or if `$servertitle` is an array

```
if(array_intersect($servertitle), $djs)) {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM djcrew WHERE djname IN ("' . implode('", "', $djs) . '")';

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

Comment: this is almost what i want.
The thing i miss is that there is a match with servertitle and the djname from the database.

The servertitle is like dj test playing music for you ( that is where i thought to use preg_match )

Comment: i get the value of $servertitle from the shoutcast server. i want to match $servertitle ( see script above ) with the list of dj's.   the property of $servertitle is like "DJ Test playing music for you"

Comment: Updated code so $servertitle will be a string and checks the array to see if there is a match. If so do the next part of code

Comment: i tried it and the output is the same. i get all the rows and the string $servertitle is not matched

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63232/discussion-between-adrock-and-patrick-j).

Comment: Yes i have. but it wont work.
Why i have tried it with preg_match is because the match name is imported to get the dj info

Comment: What does $servertitle show? This part `if(in_array($servertitle, $djs) {` checks to see if $servertitle is in the database and if so show the details. I got it to work